# Что значит тестовое задание "в 2 экрана"?

Tags: java, android, задание-на-собеседовании

Отправил резюме, получил в ответ вопрос: "готовы ли вы выполнить небольшое тестовое задание в 2 экрана?".

Я то готов, только не знаю, что это такое. Погуглил, ответа не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это такое?

Comment: не, ну может Вам понадобиться два экрана монитора для тестового задания оО

Comment: Собеседование на какую должность? Из меток можно подумать, что на Android-разработчика, угадал? Укажите в вопросе явно.

Comment: у меня ассоциации на фразу *"небольшое тестовое задание в 2 экрана"*, то что [решение] код 2 экрана занимает (50-200 строк).

Comment: да, android-разработчик. вопрос был указан явна.

Answer (score 3):

Под

> тестовое задание в 2 экрана

очевидно, имелось ввиду приложение, в котором два экрана (скорее всего – две активити, а может и два фрагмента).

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1:**

Вам дадут небольшое задание и вы будете делать его прям во время разговора по скайпу, как будто вы на собеседовании, такое часто используется в фирмах, если не ошибаюсь, то первым этапом собеседования в гугл является скайп беседа

**Вариант 2:**

Вам дадут небольшое задание в котором будет больше чем 1 activity (возможно и фрагменты), чтобы проверить как вы справитесь с построением, передачей данных, проверить ваши знания жизненное цикла, тд.

**Успехов.**